# SQL query performance issues NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql

I have the following SQL query that is bottlenecking at some point.  It will make it halfway through around 900 records it returns before timing out. When I change my second select to only return certain columns it helped a bit but it is still bottlenecking somewhere.

I'm thinking there is something wrong with the way that I have the JOINs written but could use any advice.

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM TABLE1 B
INNER JOIN TABLE2 A ON B.ID_NBR = A.ID_NBR
INNER JOIN TABLE3 L ON A.CUST_NUM = L.CUST_NUM
WHERE B.SUPP_NBR = '17' AND STAT_NUM <> 4 AND BGHT_ID is not null 
AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE4 A WHERE A.ID_NBR = B.ID_NBR)) APPL
INNER JOIN TABLE5 ON M.PRSN_NUM = PRSN_NUM
WHERE M.LOC_ID = 'US' and (APPL.STAT_CD <> 'S' OR (APPL.STAT_CD = 
'S' AND M.TXT_LOC != 
'UNKNOWN'));
```

UPDATE: I ended up using a LEFT JOIN instead of NOT EXISTS, changed the SELECT *, and used GROUP BY to correct the indexing issue:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT B.ID_NBR, B.SUPP_NBR, B.STAT_NUM, B.BGHT_ID, A.CUST_NUM, 
L.CUST_NUM, L.STAT_CD FROM TABLE1 B

INNER JOIN TABLE2 A ON B.ID_NBR = A.ID_NBR
INNER JOIN TABLE3 L ON A.CUST_NUM = L.CUST_NUM
LEFT JOIN TABLE4 C ON C.ID_NBR = B.ID_NBR
WHERE C.ID_NBR is null AND B.SUPP_NBR = '17' AND B.STAT_NUM <> 4 
AND B.BGHT_ID is not null 

GROUP BY B.ID_NBR, B.SUPP_NBR, B.STAT_NUM, B.BGHT_ID, A.CUST_NUM, 
L.CUST_NUM, L.STAT_CD) 
APPL
INNER JOIN TABLE5 ON M.PRSN_NUM = PRSN_NUM
WHERE M.LOC_ID = 'US' and 
(APPL.STAT_CD <> 'S' OR M.TXT_LOC != 'UNKNOWN');
```

Comment: please run A EXPLAIN SELECT... and also show the tables with the indexes you use. twith that many joins such query tend to get slow depending on granularity

Comment: I do not have the privilege to use explain

Comment: exchange the non exists to a join, but you posted not much information like create table data and result a [mre] but performnce qzestion need the explain

Comment: Speed issues like this almost always come down to inadequate table indexes.

Also, take a few minutes to read on join types to ensure you are solving it correctly.

https://www.guru99.com/joins.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm new to asking questions here so I'll learn how to produce a minimal reproducible example with info I'm allowed to provide.  I'll review join types as well to see if this is solving correctly.

Comment: FYI I was able to resolve the issue, you all were correct and it was a table index issue I was able to use GROUP BY to improve the performance of this query.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can't help you without knowing which tables these are in:                    AND  STAT_NUM <> 4
                  AND  BGHT_ID is not null

Comment: `GROUP BY` helped??  Let's see what you ended up with.

Comment: both those are found in TABLE1

Answer (score 0):

Can't this

```
           (APPL.STAT_CD <> 'S'
       OR  (APPL.STAT_CD = 'S' AND  M.TXT_LOC != 'UNKNOWN')
           )
```

be simplified to

```
(APPL.STAT_CD <> 'S' OR M.TXT_LOC != 'UNKNOWN')
```

(It probably won't speed up the query much.)

Some of these indexes may help:

```
M:  INDEX(LOC_ID, TXT_LOC, PRSN_NUM)
APPL:  INDEX(STAT_CD)
B:  INDEX(SUPP_NBR, ID_NBR)
A:  INDEX(ID_NBR,  CUST_NUM)
L:  INDEX(CUST_NUM)
```